# How to prevent Opera from switching to the Download tab?

Tags: opera, browser-tabs

How do I prevent Opera from switching to the Download tab? 
How to disable the Download tab?

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on `Tools menu / Transfers` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to open the Transfers tab:

   [image: 1]
2. In the Transfers tab, click on the **View** button and select **Never Show When Starting Download** or **Show in Background When Starting Download** as per your preference

   [image: 2]

Note: You can always press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to view the tab in future if you turned it off completely by selecting the **Never Show** option.